# How to enable Reader Mode icon in editor window in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

There used to be a Reader Mode icon in the top-right corner of the editor window. But currently it isn't shown.

Did I removed it by changing a setting and can it be enabled to show again in the editor? Or was it removed in the current PyCharm 2021.1.1 Professional version?

The first screenshot below is how my editor looks currently.

[image]

The second screenshot shows how the icon was formerly displayed (also featured in the [Reader mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reader-mode.html) documentation page).

[image: image of editor with Reader mode icon]

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need it?

Comment: @PavelKarateev 1ºBecause it looked really good. 2ºIt was convenient to quickly check if a cross-reference was broken. 3ºI wanted to begin using [external documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-python-external-documentation.html) format and having the functionality would enhance the experience.

Answer (score 3):

As @Tomerikoo pointed out, reader mode is *"Available for library and read-only files"*. You must make your file read-only. To do that there is a "lock" icon at the bottom-right of your screen.
When you click it, you make that file "read-only", then the icon you're looking for appears.

Here:

[image]

You can also change setting for "reader mode in : Setting/Editor/Reader Mode

Comment: Indeed in the settings of Reader Mode it says *"Available for library and read-only files"* which explains the need to "lock" the file

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary I just tried this using read-only, changing to Reader Mode in Settings, and also [installing/uninstalling as a library](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-a-local-src-tree) but none of the attempts worked. The icon just isn't showing no matter what I do.

Comment: @bad_coder Is there any Reader Mode icon when you ctrl+click on a built-in function like `print` which takes you to the implementation?

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary also no. (Very good idea by the way trying with a built-in function). Still no Reader Mode icon :(

Comment: @bad_coder I'm almost embarrassed saying this but did you try Reinstalling Pycharm, restarting the computer etc. ? (the solution in the answer works for me on PyCharm 2021.1.1 (Community Edition))

Comment: @Tomerikoo everything except clearing IDE wide settings and reinstall. This happens across all projects. So my guess is, at this point, something is stuck in an IDE wide setting file (or some unrelated setting is causing this one not to work).