# How to toggle on reader mode icon in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, reader

somehow i have dismissed reader mode icon in IntelliJ and now I cannot get it back. I have searched the internet, somebody had the same problem as me: [How to enable Reader Mode icon in editor window in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653053/how-to-enable-reader-mode-icon-in-editor-window-in-pycharm)
but it was not resolved.

The problem is:
[My IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1kIq.jpg)

I want it to look like it was before - something like this, where I can toggle reader mode by mouse:

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6pnu.jpg)

I have checked the settings under Editor>Reader Mode but there isn't any option for toggling the reader mode icon. Don't know where to search for the answer, can anyone help me with toggling this as it was before?

I asked IntelliJ support for help, the problem can be resolved by unchecking compact view in here:
[Image resolving problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL694.png)

Comment: Hello! Ii should be shown for non-project files (e.g. library classes).

Comment: I have already found a solution, thanks